# Finding the radius of curvature of the trajectory of a projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, curvature, projectile

The parabolic trajectory of a projectile has different radius of curvature at different points of time. Is there a way to find R of C  for a simple projectile, thrown at an angle θ and initial velocity v0 from level ground.

Comment: If you can find the equation of the projectile then the rest is trivial. Can you find that ?

Comment: How does Exercise 3.61 define the radius of curvature?

Comment: *this is the first one of its type* I don’t know what that means. Exercise 3.62 explicitly says that the radius of curvature is defined in Exercise 3.61. But you haven’t told us this definition, so you are leaving out something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of curvature of a curve $y(x)$ is given by the simple formula,
$R=|\frac{(1+y^{\prime 2})^{3/2}}{y^{\prime \prime}}|$ where $y^{\prime}$ denotes derivative w.r.t $x$. You know the equation of the trajectory,
$$y=x \tan \theta-\frac{g x^2}{2 v_0^2\cos ^2 \theta}$$ Plug in and get $R$ as a function of $x$. Plug in values of $x$ as mentioned in the problem and you should have the answer.

Comment: @bipratipb, based on Exercise 3.61, the book wants you to use the velocity and acceleration to compute the radius of curvature. That is a very different, and more *physical*, approach compared with applying the formula in this answer.

Comment: @G.Smith I would assume if he did 3.61 he has derived the parametric form of this formula because that's exactly what the answer to that question is. If he hasn't well, that's his loss tbh.

Comment: Since the hint is “You know $v$ and $a$”, I think the intention is to use $a_\text{normal}=v^2/R$ to calculate $R$ in both exercises. This is what I meant by a “more physical” approach. I am not criticizing your correct answer, but I do not think it makes the physical meaning of the radius of curvature obvious, and I think it ignores the hint.

Comment: @G.Smith fair enough.